# When calling findAll() from jpa repository that table is getting updated

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

When I am calling this findAll() from repository the product table is updating.I need to restrict of updating product table.

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product,BigInteger>{

}

public Product getProductData(){

        Product product = productRepository.findAll();
        return product;

    }
```

Comment: this should not update the table

Comment: show your real running code.

Comment: You absolutly run something else with it, this would never update a table

Comment: If it's possible can you share `what data` is getting updated? As long as the above code is concerned, it will not update the data at all! Try adding the calling code to `getProductData()`

Comment: Ideally I think findAll() will return a list and I am not sure how you manage it capturing against an Object